# Increase Space between Headings & Paragraphs

Tags: html, css

If you run below Snippet, you can see there is much space between **headings & Paragraphs.**

Means Between "1. Access to ports, controls and sensors" & " All Cases"

but in site, its displaying like below image :

[image]

so I want to increase space between "headings & Paragraphs."

Also I want to increase space between each words & i want to display like below image :

[image]

```html
<div class="product-size-space-img"><img alt="" src="/media/wysiwyg/new-image.jpg" /></div>
<div class="product-size-space-content">
   <b>1. Access to ports, controls and sensors</b>
   <p>All cases we sell have access to all ports, buttons, camera and sensors, there won&rsquo;t be any interference with your phone censors. Fully compatible with regular charges and headphones.</p>
   <b>2. Protect it from bumps and drops</b>
   <p>This case is made of light, durable and slim material called polycarbonate, it is hard plastic with high impact resistance and low scratch resistance. It is flexible enough to snap on to your phone with ease and strong enough to protect it from&ensp;&ensp; bumps, scratches and accidental drops.</p>
   <b>3.Lay-flat bezel raise lip </b>
   <p>Raised lip around the sides of the case protects your screen from directly contacting surfaces on accidents drops.</p>
   <b>4. High quality printing</b>
   <p>Site1 name uses image transfer technologies which results high quality designs embedded right onto the surface of the phones cases, so there won&rsquo;t be any peeling off or wearing off or chipping on your case design.</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code for space between heading and paragraph and also each word space:

```css
p {
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-size-space-img"><img alt="" src="/media/wysiwyg/new-image.jpg" /></div>
<div class="product-size-space-content">
<b>1. Access to ports, controls and sensors</b>
<p>All cases we sell have access to all ports, buttons, camera and sensors, there won&rsquo;t be any interference with your phone censors. Fully compatible with regular charges and headphones.</p>
<b>2. Protect it from bumps and drops</b>
<p>This case is made of light, durable and slim material called polycarbonate, it is hard plastic with high impact resistance and low scratch resistance. It is flexible enough to snap on to your phone with ease and strong enough to protect it from&ensp;&ensp; bumps, scratches and accidental drops.</p>
<b>3.Lay-flat bezel raise lip </b>
<p>Raised lip around the sides of the case protects your screen from directly contacting surfaces on accidents drops.</p>
<b>4. High quality printing</b>
<p>Site1 name uses image transfer technologies which results high quality designs embedded right onto the surface of the phones cases, so there won&rsquo;t be any peeling off or wearing off or chipping on your case design.</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `margin` & add `line-height` on `p` `tag`

```
p {
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase space between "headings & Paragraphs, you can use br :)

To increase space between each words you have to work with CSS style

Comment: *Br will skip a line, if you want a little space you can't use it